# Heroku deploy fails on build

Tags: reactjs, git, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy my React application with Node to Heroku, but my build every time fails. I tried to google this issue but no luck, nothing works for me. Any suggestions?

I have a client and server folder. Here is my package:

```
{
 "name": "game",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"start": "node server/server.js",
"server": "nodemon server/server.js",
"client": "npm run start --prefix client",
"dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
},
"engines": {
"node":"8.11.2"
},
 "author": "Rijel Ek",
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
 "bcrypt": "^1.0.3",
 "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
 "concurrently": "^3.5.1",
"cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
"express": "^4.16.2",
"jsonwebtoken": "^8.0.1",
"moment-js": "^1.1.15",
"mongoose": "^4.10.8"
 }
}
```

and client package:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
   "private": true,
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "concat": "^1.0.3",
    "gsap": "^2.0.2",
    "gsap-react-plugin": "^1.0.2",
    "jquery": "^1.11.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.4",
    "node-sass-chokidar": "^1.3.3",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.3",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.4.0",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.1.43",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.0.5",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.5.0",
    "react-vanilla-tilt": "^1.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-promise": "^0.6.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "simplebar": "^3.1.0"
  },
   "scripts": {
     "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./public/ --include-  path ./node_modules public/sass -o public/css",
     "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./public/ --include-path ./node_modules public/sass -o public/css --watch --recursive",
    "concat:css": "concat -o public/css/style.concat.css public/css/icon-font.css public/css/style.comp.css",
    "start-js": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
    "build": "run build-css && react-scripts build"
 },
       "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
      },
        "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
        "browserslist": [
           ">0.2%",
           "not dead",
           "not ie <= 11",
           "not op_mini all"
        ]
      }
```

My git: https://github.com/RijelEk/quantumterminals and error:

```
Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json)
remote:
remote:        > bcrypt@1.0.3 install   /tmp/build_b88b5b046b6badf32aa7f0f12359d44e/node_modules/bcrypt
remote:        > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
remote:
remote:        [bcrypt] Success: "/tmp/build_b88b5b046b6badf32aa7f0f12359d44e/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node" is installed via remote
remote:        added 222 packages in 9.237s
remote:        Running heroku-postbuild
remote:
remote:        > game@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_b88b5b046b6badf32aa7f0f12359d44e
remote:        > NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client
remote:
remote: npm ERR! code E404
remote: npm ERR! 404 Not Found: event-stream@https://registry.npmjs.org/event-stream/-/event-stream-3.3.6.tgz
remote:
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.x1ms6/_logs/2018-12-05T16_06_23_947Z-debug.log
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! game@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR!
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the game@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.x1ms6/_logs/2018-12-05T16_06_23_983Z-debug.log
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy....
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

event-stream 3.3.6 was removed from npm due to malicious code being added (you can read more about it here: https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/11/26/npm_repo_bitcoin_stealer/). Update the package and you should be fine.